# Grid on HTML5 canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm making an HTML5 canvas game and I want to make a grid. The map is infinite, and I want there to be a grid on the ground. But whatever I do, the same gets slower and slower over time and just gets too laggy to play.
Here's my current draw grid function.

```
function drawGrid() {
    for (x=0;x<=canvas.width;x+=80) {
        ctx.moveTo(x, offset[0] % 80);
        ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height + offset[0] % 80);
    }
    for (y=0;y<=canvas.height;y+=80) {
        ctx.moveTo(offset[1] % 80, y);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width + offset[1] % 80, y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

I Just don't exactly understand why it gets so laggy.

EDIT: The canvas is cleared every frame by drawing a rectangle over everything, and this function runs every frame

I also don't think it's a different part of my code, If I run it without this function it doesn't lag.

Comment: I assume the issue isn't in this piece of code and it's somewhere else.

Comment: When I delete the code, It isn't laggy anymore.

Comment: Is it getting slower over time or as you're scrolling away? Try removing every `ctx`-related command, and just do `offset[0] % 80; offset[1] % 80`, see if the slowdown is the same.